# What is the different between Amazon Kinesis data stream and DynamoDB stream details

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using dynamodb and I'd like to enable dynamodb stream to process any data change in the dynamodb table. By looking at the stream options, there are two streams `Amazon Kinesis data stream and DynamoDB stream`. From the doc of these two streams, both are handling the data change from dynamodb table but I am not sure what the main different between using these two.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are quite a few of the differences, which are listed in:

- [Streaming Options for Change Data Capture](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/streamsmain.html)

Few notable ones are that `DynamoDB Streams`, unlike `Kinesis Data Streams for DynamoDB`, guarantees **no duplicates**, the record retention time is only **24 hours**, and the are throughout capacity limits.

Comment: how could duplicate happen? is it because the record is not in-order when comes to kinesis stream?

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao Some reasons are listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/kinesis-record-processor-duplicates.html).

Comment: Yes I have read it. But why dynamodb stream doesn't have duplication issue. It seems duplication only happens on Kinesis data stream?

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao Don't know. Guess `dynamodb stream` are specially designed for that, unlike `Kinesis data stream`.

Answer (score 0):

Another important difference is that **DynamoDB Streams guarantees order** while Kinesis (associated with a DynamoDB table) does not.